# Cannot remove directory ${env.DELETED_ITEMS} on Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have created a directory on my RedHat machine which has the name `${env.DELETED_ITEMS}`. Well, I did not intend to create it, it just got created when i ran my Ant build without setting the correct environment variable. Now, I am unable to remove it. I tried renaming the directory, `rm -rf`, none of them works. Could anybody explain why this is the behavior and how to get rid of it?

I get this error:

`-bash: ${env.DELETED_ITEMS}: bad substitution`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in single quotes to prevent parameter expansion:

```
rm -r '${env.DELETED_ITEMS}'
```

Alternative you will need to escape the special characters:

```
rm -r \$\{env.DELETED_ITEMS}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to delete it with the double hypen syntax.

```
rm -r -- '${env.DELETED_ITEMS}'
```

This way everything after `--` is treated as input.
Or you simple escape those chars. Problem is you are missing the last escape char.

```
rm \$\{env.DELETED_ITEMS\}
```

Comment: Although double dash is good `--` it have nothing to do with solving OP's problem. I actually removed it from my answer, so they wouldn't cause confusion :-)